# Why is the object being iterated passed back through the callback?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This is a common idiom encapsualted into a function by [undescore.](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js)

```
_.each(obj1, function(val, key, context, obj2){
});
```

What is the purpose of the 4th argument in the callback - `obj2`.  This is the object one is looping through so it should always be available in the outer scope as `obj1`.

Is there an example of where you would need access to `obj1` through `obj2`.

I'm trying to understand what `obj2` is for.  Here is the exact line of code - line 83.

```
if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
```

Comment: You can easily build an example where it is not in the scope of the iterator function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were passing a reference to a named function as the callback, `obj1` might not be available:

```
function my_callback(val, key, context, obj2) {
    ...
}

function do_stuff() {
    var obj1 = ...
    _.each(obj1, my_callback);
}
```

Comment: (the function doesn't need to be named)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of the 4th argument in the callback - `obj2`. This is the object one is looping through so it should always be available in the outer scope as `obj1`.

It's so you can reuse the same function for looping through multiple objects, and still have access to the object being iterated within the function. The function you use might well be define elsewhere. You could have a library of functions you use for various iteration purposes. It's *rare* to want to know what the object is (hence it being so far into the argument list), but there are use cases.